# How to say "Contact Me" for email

Tags: grammar, translation, email

I would like to say the following in Japanese: **contact**, **contact me** and **email here**.  Would the following suffice:

**"Contact"** as in: contact:abc@mail.com.  Is it simply: **コンタック** / **Kontakku** ?

**Contact Me** as in contact me:abc@mail.com. Would it be **Watashi ni renraku shite** is there a simpler way to say this?

**Email Here** as in email here:abc@mail.com  **メールはこちら** / **Mēru wa kochira**

Comment: Can you give some context?  This seems very vague to me.  Is this one a web page somewhere?  In a mobile app?  On a piece of paper?  Are you using them as a form?  In complete sentences?

Comment: As an English speaker, the phrases `Email Here` and `Contact me` come off as slightly unnatural and almost desperate.  Maybe it's just me.  I think that it would be a lot more clear if you did the following: `Email: abc@mail.com`  *It all depends on context though*.  Are you putting this on a business card?  Or, is it for more personal reasons?

Comment: No, not for a business card, website or app, just a general question was wondering what the best way would be to write those phrases if you had to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really matters on the context, but below I have provided two examples.

The best way to get it across in a business setting would be:

> こちらに連絡（れんらく)してください。(Kochira ni Renraku shitekudasai.)
>
> メールアドレス：abc@mail.com

If it is casual, just a simple:

> メールはabc@mail.comです。

Would work great.

I hope this helped! Please notify me if clarification would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The following should suffice:

これからはこのアドレスにメールを送ってください。

アドレス：abc@mail.com

Answer (score 0):

There is no such word as コンタック.
連絡{れんらく} is used usually for phone calls.
メールはこちら is OK.
You could also say メールアドレス.